# Как проверить есть ли что то в папке? Или вообще существует ли она?

Tags: java, android

программа должна проверять существует ли папка? И если нет, то сказать юзеру что такой папки нет. Нашел много примеров в которых обьясняется как проверить существует ли файл, но мне нужно знать существует ли директория? Все методы

```
boolean x = context.getExternalFilesDir("/nicknameOfUser/").exists();
    Toast.makeText(context, "ExternalFilesDir : " + x, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

`isAbsolute()`, `isDirectory()`, `isFile()`, создают новый путь к папке `files - nicknameOfUser` мне не нужно чтоб они создавались, мне нужно просто чтоб программа вернула есть что то по указаному пути или нет...

**Как это сделать?** Мне кажется это вопрос из разряда стандартных, но я не могу понять...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String fileDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile() + "/nicknameOfUser/";
File file = new File(fileDir);
boolean x = file.exists();
```

Данный метод работает, т.е. возвращает булевское значение и не создает папку `nicknameOfUser`.

Comment: Да! Точно! Спасибо)) Я уже почти думал что это не возможно))

Comment: Вот вернулся к этому методу, в тот раз не хватило времени все довести до конца и обнаружил, что он в любом случае возвращает 'false'...  Даже когда папка создана... Не знаете почему так может быть?

Comment: Не уточнил у вас сразу. Где должна лежать папка, которую вы создаете: /data/data/название пакета/*, storage/sdcard0/Android/data/название пакета/* или storage/sdcard0/ ?

Comment: Да да, точно в этом проблема я только что нашел